# Converting from mmddyyyy to yyyymmdd with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I should preface my question by saying I am *very new* to SQL (or any programming involving databases). I started learning SQL a couple of weeks ago when I decided to take on a data project.

I have been using SSMS in wrangling large tables in comma-separated text file format. I need to be able to sort by dates, and the current format is mmddyyyy, but when I try to sort by date it does not work.

I know that converting dates is something that gets asked a lot around here, but I haven't found any solutions that explain things for a newb like myself.

So far my guesses for a solution are to use the CONVERT or CAST solutions, but I'm not sure if that is the right approach. I have found several CAST/CONVERT posts but  none have really applied to my situation.

I hate to have this as my first question, but I'd thought I'd take some down vote bullets if it means I could figure this out. Thank you.

Sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT *    
  FROM [databasename].[dbo].[table1]    
 WHERE [ column1] > 01012017;
```

I get the entire table back, unsorted.

Comment: what is the column's data type?

Comment: string [DT_STR] OutputColumnWidth is 8

Comment: that's not a SQL Server data type (sounds like you are using Integration Services or similar, but please tell us the actual data type of that column in SQL Server)

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately: SSMS is a tool used to interface with SQL Server. If that's the RDBMS you're using, you should add that tag. Also: Your query doesn't have an `ORDER BY` clause, so it makes sense your data is coming back unsorted. You really need to figure out what datatype your column is (if it's a `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or some text type like `VARCHAR`).

Comment: I think the data type is a string or varchar8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your:

```
SELECT *    
  FROM [databasename].[dbo].[table1]    
 WHERE [ column1] > 01012017;
```

does not error, we could say that the [column1]'s datatype is either a character type (like VARCHAR, char), or datetime.

Since you are getting back all the data and I would think you don't have data in the future, it should be a varchar (or char) - with datetime that means 1900-01-01 + 1012017 days.

To make it a datetime you need to 'cast' your column1 which is in mmddyyyy form by first converting it to yyyymmdd style (which would work under any date and language setting):

```
cast(right([column1],4)+substring([column1],1,2)+substring([column1],3,2) as datetime)
```

and you would write that 01012017 as a string (quotes around) and also again in yyyymmdd format (it would be implicitly casted to datetime):

```
'20170101'
```

So your SQL becomes:

```
SELECT *    
  FROM [databasename].[dbo].[table1]    
 WHERE cast(right([column1],4) + 
            substring([column1],1,2) + 
            substring([column1],3,2) as datetime) > '20170101';
```

Having a date\datetime column as varchar and using like this would render the ability to use simple indexes but that is another matter. For now, this would return the data you want.

Comment: Incredible. Thank you. This worked. I don't fully understand how but I hope to continue learning as I go. Thank you everyone.

Comment: If this is a database you control, you need to change your datatype to `DATE` (or `DATETIME`). Storing dates as `VARCHAR`s will lead to countless problems down the road.

Comment: @Zack, thank you. I figured this is true. I just needed a quick fix for now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column's datatype is [Date], try something similar to:

```
SELECT *
FROM [databasename].[dbo].[table1]
WHERE FORMAT([column1],'dd/MM/yyyy') >'01012017'
```

If it's string format, you'll have to use CONVERT() to convert the column to Date with a query like

```
SELECT *
FROM [databasename].[dbo].[table1]
WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), [Column1], 112) >'01012017'
```

Refer to [this W3Schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp) if you need more help with the CONVERT clause

Comment: but it's likely that's not a date data type, otherwise the op wouldn't have an issue ordering them

Comment: Even if it doesn't work out, something like this will give OP an idea of where to start, or what to look for. FORMAT, CONVERT, and a helpful article.

Comment: I would argue it's premature to argue when we don't know the data type. Also, I would argue it's better to link to SQL Server documentation than to W3Schools.

Comment: If you're a novice to SQL or SSIS I believe that W3Schools is less intimidating than Microsoft documentation. The guy is a new user with a pretty well-formatted post with a fair question. That's a lot better than most other new users. Even if my answer isn't perfect, it still might assist.

Comment: Yep. Data type is VARCHAR. PausePuase, thanks for your suggestion. Zack, I will try to use an ORDER BY clause. Will have to learn how to use it though. Thanks.

Comment: @SupaDupa, this wouldn't work because you would be suppressing the error BUT doing an alpha sort. For example '31122016' is greater than '01012017' BUT date wise it is not.